# How to place two q-drawers on the left side by side

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Is it possible to place two q-drawers on the left, side by side?

```
<!--
Forked from:
https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer#example--basic
-->
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
<div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-layout view="hHh Lpr fFf" container style="height: 300px" class="shadow-2 rounded-borders">
      <q-header elevated :class="$q.dark.isActive ? 'bg-secondary' : 'bg-black'">
        <q-toolbar>
          <q-btn flat @click="drawerLeft = !drawerLeft" round dense icon="menu"></q-btn>          
           <q-btn flat @click="drawerLeft2 = !drawerLeft2" round dense icon="menu"></q-btn>
          <q-toolbar-title>Header</q-toolbar-title>
          
        </q-toolbar>
      </q-header>

      <q-drawer
        v-model="drawerLeft"
        show-if-above
        :width="200"
        :breakpoint="700"
        elevated
        class="bg-primary text-white"
      >
        <q-scroll-area class="fit">
          <div class="q-pa-sm">
            <div v-for="n in 50" :key="n">Drawer {{ n }} / 50</div>
          </div>
        </q-scroll-area>
      </q-drawer>
      
         <q-drawer
        v-model="drawerLeft2"
        show-if-above
        :width="150"
        :breakpoint="700"
        elevated
        class="bg-red text-white"
      >
        <q-scroll-area class="fit">
          <div class="q-pa-sm">
            <div v-for="n in 50" :key="n">Drawer {{ n }} / 50</div>
          </div>
        </q-scroll-area>
      </q-drawer>

      <q-page-container>
        <q-page padding>
          <p v-for="n in 15" :key="n">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          </p>
        </q-page>
      </q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
  </div>
</div>
const { ref } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    return {
      drawerLeft: ref(false),
      drawerLeft2: ref(false)
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

https://codepen.io/ijose/pen/PoXKKQy?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using left css property to the width of the first q-drawer.

[image: side by side q-drawer using quasar]

Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasar-wpplumber?file=src%2Flayouts%2FMainLayout.vue) to a solution.

In short the style to usebelow:

```
    <style>
.q-drawer-container:nth-child(1) > .q-drawer--left {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  background: transparent;
}
.q-drawer-container:nth-child(2) > .q-drawer--left {
  margin-left: 300px !important;
  background: transparent;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: something fails in your example that is not working

Comment: what was the issue in the example? anyway I posted the solution as code too.

Comment: The q-drawers are not side by side like in your image. The q-drawers are on top of each other

Comment: It is a bit late but I changed the link solution to fix your problem.